# In computer graphic, normalization

Tags: graphics

What is the purpose of using a normalizing transformation in the viewing pipeline? 
Is it about of good appearance of viewing pipeline on the different display device?

Comment: what do you mean by normalizing transformation? There could be `normal` transformation matrix and normalization of vectors (color,normals,etc) ... so which is it?